# Are Coroutines preemptive or just blocking the thread that picked the Runnable?

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

after digging a bit inside implementations of the Coroutine dispatchers such as "Default" and "IO",
I see they are just containing a Java executor (which is a simple thread pool) and a queue of Runnables which are the coroutine logic blocks.

let's take an example scenario where I am launching 10,000 coroutines on the same coroutine context, "Default" dispatcher for example, which contains an Executor with 512 real threads in its pool.

those coroutines will be added to the dispatcher queue (in case the number of in-flight coroutines exceeded the max threshold).

let's assume for example that the first 512 coroutines I launched out of the 10,000 are really slow and heavy.

are the rest of my coroutines will be blocked until at least 1 of my real threads will finish,
or is there some time-slicing mechanism in those "user-space threads"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coroutines are scheduled cooperatively, not pre-emptively, so context switch is possible only at suspension points. This is actually by design, it makes execution much faster, because coroutines don't fight each other and the number of context switches is lower than in pre-emptive scheduling.

But as you noticed, it has drawbacks. If performing long CPU-intensive calculations it is advised to invoke [yield()](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/yield.html) from time to time. It allows to free the thread for other coroutines. Another solution is to create a distinct thread pool for our calculations to separate them from other parts of the application. This has similar drawback as pre-emptive scheduling - it will make coroutines/threads fight for the access to CPU cores.

Comment: thanks for the answer. in the specific example I provided yield() will not help since all the threads in the specific context already picked a heavy runnable, so the better option is to create a dedicated pool instead

Comment: Note this is not `Thread.yield()`, but `yield()` function specific for coroutines. I'm also not sure if you know/understand that the coroutine does not need to finish to free the thread. It is enough that it will suspend and then the thread switches to executing another coroutine. What does it mean that your tasks are "heavy"? They are CPU-intensive or just long-ruinning tasks, involving e.g. IO operations, etc.?

Comment: by heavy I mean there are no suspension points inside, just a CPU intensive code block

Comment: @broot I would suggest rephrasing *"This is actually by design"*, because when reading it seems that you're referring to cooperative scheduling, but I think you're referring to preemptive here.

Comment: @Dev93 See if that cpu intensive work can be divided into chunks and you call yield after each chunk gets completed

Comment: Ok, if you have CPU-intensive operations without yields/suspension points and you can't add them, then I guess it is best to create a separate thread pool. Using `Dispatchers.Default` would degrade the performance of any other code using this dispatcher. Of course, if your app does not do anything else than these CPU-intensive tasks, it may be not needed.

Comment: @Joffrey I meant that coroutines were designed in the way that allows us to write the code that is scheduled cooperatively, instead of pre-emptively. This is one of futures of coroutines. So yes, I really meant that coroutines were designed to be scheduled cooperatively. Do you think this is not true?

Comment: "features", not "futures"

Comment: @broot I'm sorry I literally read "BAD design" instead of "BY design", hence why I assumed you were referring to preemptive scheduling... please ignore my comment

Comment: It's not exactly by design that coroutines are cooperative, it's a limitation that comes from the fact that Kotlin doesn't control the JVM. Java's own coroutines (the Loom project) will have an additional mechanism that will allow suspension to occur at any safepoint as well, not just at the points where blocking calls are invoked. This will give them the best of both worlds -- multitasking on a single thread _and_ pre-emptive suspension of non-cooperative code.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Maybe this is just my point of view, but for me cooperative scheduling is the essence of coroutines, it is one of the main features provided by them. You can't achieve fully cooperative multitasking with threads. But if you need pre-emptive multitasking with coroutines then just start more threads than CPU cores and you will get it, Wikipedia for both coroutines and fibers specifies that cooperative scheduling is their main feature and the main difference between them and threads.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Also, I'm not very familiar with Loom yet, but note that documentation in most places says it provides lightweight threads, virtual threads or userspace threads. In other languages they are sometimes called "green threads" and in fact, wikipedia lists Project Loom as one of implementations of green threads. Loom docs sometimes speaks about fibers - I'm not sure if this is by mistake or there is a good reason to do this.

Comment: The _cooperative_ property isn't actually what you want, it means the runtime can't switch tasks at its discretion, it needs cooperation from user code. What you want is avoid starting and managing expensive OS-level threads and context-switching among them. Project Loom has it both because it can do stuff not visible at the bytecode level, like switching tasks at any safepoint. The terms "coroutine", "green thread", "userspace thread" etc. are overlapping and you have to study each implementation to be able to compare them and draw analogies.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik "The cooperative property isn't actually what you want," - I don't think this is entirely true. Cooperative code may be considered somewhat harder to write, because... well, it has to cooperate, so it requires discipline. But it has advantages as well: it has better performance, even if context switches are fast and in many cases it allows to not synchronize or it makes synchronization easier.

Comment: I think you are now assuming a single-threaded dispatcher, where you basically have a critical section between any two suspension points. Yes, it's certainly easier to program with that assumption, but it isn't tied to the concept of coroutines. The same assumption works in plain event-oriented GUI programming, as well as all of JavaScript. Kotlin coroutines are orthogonal to that, being a system that supports multithreaded coroutine dispatchers on an equal footing with single-threaded ones.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Yes, I meant single-threaded event-driven architecture. We use this technique mostly to achieve cooperative scheduling in a purely preemptive environment. It allows to write the code that can switch the context at specific points only. And yes, we can do this without coroutines, but the code will be asynchronous which means: ugly, hard to read and to maintain. With coroutines we write a regular synchronous code, we start multiple "workers" and they still work single-threaded and switch cooperatively. So I wouldn't say coroutines have nothing to do with this concept.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Also, when I said there are performance benefits, I didn't mean event-driven architecture. I believe cooperative scheduling is just more performant, for many reasons. But this is not a strong opinion, it is not based on hard proofs and experience - I may be wrong here.

Comment: Clearly, on a multicore CPU, single-threaded cooperative scheduling can't possibly beat multithreaded cooperative scheduling. So you don't get to keep your desirable property of single-threaded coroutines if you want 100% CPU utilization. RE: `I wouldn't say coroutines have nothing to do with this concept.` -- neither would I.

Comment: `when I said there are performance benefits, I didn't mean event-driven architecture. I believe cooperative scheduling is just more performant` -- I didn't quite get your point here. Event-driven programming _is_ cooperative programming, just using a different programming model. Specifically, when you are using the `Main` dispatcher with Kotlin coroutines, execution happens in exactly the same way as if written in the event-driven paradigm. Another example is Microsoft Windows before version 95, it was described as a system that does "cooperative multitasking", it was an event-driven system.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Yes, it seems you just don't understand that I talk about two distinct (potential) advantages of cooperative scheduling and they have nothing to do with each other. First is simpler or no synchronization when using cooperative scheduling with a single thread. This can be done with or without coroutines, but with them it is much easier/better. Another is performance benefits and it is unrelated to whether we use single or multiple threads. But as I said, I don't have any numbers to proof the latter claim, so I may be wrong here.

Comment: They do have something to do with each other -- they are mutually exclusive. In order to have simplified concurrency on a single thread, you must forego the ability to use any more than a single core. In order to utilize all of the CPU cores, you must face the fact that your program is prone to data races.

Comment: Also, the _cooperative_ aspect of scheduling isn't the one that gives you the performance advantage -- Loom fibers have preemptive scheduling while also retaining the performance advantage of userspace task switching.

Answer (score 2):

Once a coroutine starts executing it will continue to do so until it hits a suspension point, which is introduced by a call to [`suspendCoroutine`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines/suspend-coroutine.html) or [`suspendCancellableCoroutine`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/suspend-cancellable-coroutine.html).

### Suspension is the fundamental idea

This however is by design, because suspension is fundamental to the performance gains that are introduced by coroutines, whole point behind coroutines is that ***why keep blocking a thread when its doing nothing but wait (ex sync IO). why not use this thread to do something else***

### Without suspension you lose much of the performance gain

So in order to identify the switch in your particular case, you will have to define the term `slow and heavy`. A cpu intensive task such as generating a prime number can be slow and heavy and a API call which performs complex computation on server and then returns a result can also be slow and heavy. if 512 coroutines have no suspension point, then others will have to wait for them to complete. which actually defeats the whole point of using the coroutines, since you are effectively using coroutiens as a replacement for threads but with added overhead.

***If you have to execute bunch of non-suspending operations in parallel, you should instead use a service like Executor, since in this case coroutines does nothing but add a useless layer of abstraction.***

Comment: thanks for your answer. I still don't get one simple thing, correct me if I am wrong please. moving aside all those nice levels of abstractions Kotlin introduce, under the hood, if there is a real blocking call (e.g network / IO). a real OS thread once picking a Runnable instance with this logic will be blocked while executing this low-level operation, we just can not run from it. am I right or I am missing something here?